# Get Field Label dynamically with aura:changeValue in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-handler

My requirement is whenever a field is changed and is updated I need to get the field label and sent that in mail saying that the field is updated. Now by using `<aura:valueChange>` I was able to get the old and new values but I was unable to get the field Label value.

**Lightning Component:**

```
  <aura:attribute name="porductDevelopmentDetails" 
                        type="HBC_Product_Generation_Grid__c" />
     <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.updateNotifications}" disabled="{!v.disablebutton}" variant="brand" aura:id="Update1" label="Update" />
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
             <lightning:layoutitem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
                <lightning:input name="Product Name" label="Product Name" disabled="true" type="text" 
                    maxlength="80" required="true" value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails.Name}" aura:id="ProdDev_Elem" />
            </lightning:layoutitem>
    <lightning:layoutitem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
                <lightning:input name="Tier" label="Tier" disabled="{!v.disableSection}" type="text"
                                 maxlength="50"  value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails.HBC_Tier__c}" required="true"  aura:id="ProdDev_Elem" />
            </lightning:layoutitem>
    <lightning:layoutitem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
                <lightning:input name="Variation"
                    label="Variation" disabled="{!v.disableSection}"
                                 type="text"  maxlength="50" value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails.HBC_Variation__c}" required="true"  aura:id="ProdDev_Elem" />
            </lightning:layoutitem>
    <lightning:layoutitem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="6">
        <lightning:select name="APTC" disabled="{!v.disableSection}" label="APTC" value="{!v.porductDevelopmentDetails.HBC_APTC__c}" required="true"  aura:id="ProdDev_Elem" >
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </lightning:select>
            </lightning:layoutitem>
```

**Controller:**

```
itemsChange: function(cmp,evt){
console.log("old value: " + evt.getParam("oldValue"));
console.log("current value: " + evt.getParam("value")); //Along with the Values I need to get the label of the field
var componentList = cmp.find('ProdDev_Elem');
       var componentLabels = [];
componentList.forEach(function(each){
    componentLabels.push(each.get('v.label'));
}); 
console.log(componentLabels); //Here I'm getting all the list of labels
}
```

**Problem :** I was unable to fetch the particular field label that is being changed, instead getting all the list of labels

Comment: If there are not much number of fields, you can manually compare field values from old and new versions and find out OR you can use `onchange` event of the `lightning:input` and get the field label from `event.getSource()` OR this requirement seems doable through apex trigger, any specific reason of not using that?

Comment: There are around 80 fields where we are displaying it in different sections(lightning tab) in a lightning component and each section consists of a set of Team Members. Mail should be sent with the field label on a button click informing the team members that it is changed(where trigger doesnt works)